# Can Parallels use NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M indirectly?

Tags: macos, gpu, parallels-desktop

I'd like to run windows 7 via Parallels using a new 15-inch MacBook Pros with Retina display. Now, I am considering spending extra on [the model with a dedicated graphics card](http://store.apple.com/ca/buy-mac/macbook-pro?product=MGXC2LL/A&step=config#): (**NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M** )

From what I have read, Parallels cannot use the NVIDA directly (unlike Bootcamp), but I'm not clear if it can use it indirectly, and if so, in what way?

In other works, if I am running a windows software in Parallels that is visualizing large 3D data sets, how much of a difference could I expect the NVIDIA model macbook to produce in comparison to [the other 15-inch MacBook Pro with Retina display but no graphics card](http://store.apple.com/ca/buy-mac/macbook-pro?product=MGXA2LL/A&step=config#)?

Comment: Here is a good new question that similar... https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395044/is-there-a-way-to-use-accelerated-3d-graphics-from-nvidia-geforce-gt-750m-in-mac