# Is there a way to use accelerated 3D graphics from NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M in Mac OS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, graphics, driver, big-sur

Since Mac OS High Sierra, Macbook Pro Late 2013 owners complain about the inability of using their NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M dedicated graphics card to speed up 3D graphics or a second display. So after all, I was wondering if Apple, NVIDIA, or some hacker [?] did something to re-enable these old-but-gold graphics card in Mac OS Big Sur.

I know it may be the latest Mac OS officialy released for 2013 Macbooks Pro, however it doesn't mean it's too outdated to be used these days. They're still very nice pieces of hardware, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I’ve linked your question to the old one. Good find. I hope someone has news for you, reuse is such a good thing.

Comment: Please see [this question and answers](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1714/88313) regarding asking questions about Apple's beta software.  You'll need to [edit] your question to include the relevant info regarding version/build and hardware type.   Also, be sure you've opened a Feedback to Apple about this issue.